# Replacing column of inf values with 0

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to numpy but i cannot seem to get this piece of code to work.

```
item3.apply(lambda x : (x[np.isneginf(x)] = 0))
```

item3 is a vector of numpy arrays with 300 dimensions in each array.

The error thrown is invalid syntax. How do i get to achieve this function.

However, given that it is a vector of float64 numpy vectors. The datatype is object. and it throws an exception

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isinf' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Item3 is a column which contains elements which has 300 dimension each

Comment: "with 300 dimensions in each array" did you mean 300 elements?

Comment: Yes I mean it this way

Answer (score 0):

You could make something like that :

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import inf

x = np.array([inf, inf, 0]) # Create array with inf values

print x # Show x array

x[x == inf] = 0 # Replace inf by 0

print x # Show the result
```

[image]

Comment: Yes but it gives me syntax error if i do it this way

Comment: @aceminer If you make that : `item3.apply(lambda x : (x[x == inf] = 0))` ? I didn't try it for the moment